# Why is this throwing a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, debugging, nullpointerexception

I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out why I'm getting a `NullPointerException` in this code.

Here are the relevant code snippets.

(main)

```
...

    try (RawData setupData = new RawData(
            new File(fileName), log);) {

        while (true) {

            record = setupData.nextRecord();
            if (record == null) 
                break;

            System.out.println(record.getCountryCode());
            System.out.println(record.getCountryID());
            table.put(record);
            index.put(record);

            count++;

        }


    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } 

...
```

(put method)

```
public void put(DataTableRecord country) {

    this.current = country;

    try {

        this.file.seek(this.current.getCountryID() * RECORD_SIZE);
        if (!exists(this.current.getCountryID())) {

            writeExternal(this.current);
            this.size++;
            if (country.getCountryID() > this.last)
                this.last = country.getCountryID();

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } 

}
```

(writeExternal method)

```
private void writeExternal(DataTableRecord data) throws IOException {

    System.out.println(data.getCountryCode());
    this.file.writeUTF(data.getCountryCode());
    this.file.writeShort(data.getCountryID());
    this.file.writeUTF(data.getName());
    switch (data.getContinent()) {

    case AFRICA :
        this.file.writeShort(1);
        break;

    ...

    case SOUTH_AMERICA :
        this.file.writeShort(7);
        break;

    }

    this.file.writeInt(data.getArea());
    this.file.writeLong(data.getPopulation());
    this.file.writeFloat(data.getLifeExpectancy());

}
```

Every time, the loop works successfully twice, and on the third iteration gives me a `NullPointerException`. The `System.out.writeln` calls were inserted for debugging. From the `writeln` calls, I can see that the object that I pass to the `writeExternal` method is not null immediately before the method gets called. On the third iteration, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at edu.wmich.cs3310.jwhite_cotw.DataTable.writeExternal(DataTable.java:255)
    at edu.wmich.cs3310.jwhite_cotw.DataTable.put(DataTable.java:159)
    at edu.wmich.cs3310.jwhite_cotw.Setup.main(Setup.java:62)
```

I can't figure out where the `null` is coming from. How can the object be null when it wasn't `null` immediately before the method was called? Does anyone have any ideas? I should mention that the field "this.file" is a `RandomAccessFile` opened with "rw".

DataTable.java:255 is the line

```
this.file.writeUTF(data.getCountryCode());
```

DataTable.java:159 is the line

```
writeExternal(this.current);
```

and Setup.java:62 is the line

```
table.put(record);
```

Any suggestions (even just a point in the right direction) would be most appreciated.

Comment: The first step is to find out *exactly* what is `null`. In line 255, it could be either `this.file`, or `data`. Which is it?

Comment: Did you already try to put breakpoints at every step of the call chain and inspecting the elements and their properties for null?

Comment: I added two conditions, one to display a message if `this.file` was null and one to display a message if `data` was null. Neither condition was triggered.

Comment: Yep, clearly either `data` or `file` is null.  Either use a debugger to stop on line 255 and check them, or add println statements just ahead of that line to do `String.valueOf(data)` and `String.valueOf(this.file)` to see if they are null.

Comment: What is the output of this line before the exception is thrown:     `System.out.println(data.getCountryCode());` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is when parameter to `writeExternal` is `null`. So the statement is problematic

```
writeExternal(this.current);
```

if you change that to

```
writeExternal(country);
```

it could save you from error, but probably you should redesign your code to handle nullpointer exception or at least declare it using throws clause.

Comment: I don't know how that made a difference, but it immediately fixed the exception. Thank you so much! Now I just have to go in and figure out why the assignment didn't work, but thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score -1):

Because I'm psychic, I can tell what the problem is...

The countryCode field has type `Integer`, but the parameter type of `exists()` is `int`. This means that when passing countryCode to the method, the Integer is auto-unboxed to an int, but if countryCode is null this action causes an NPE.

Change the type of the parameter to Integer and make sure the method handles being passed a null.

Disclaimer: I may have the field and method names wrong, but I'm pretty sure about the general reason.

Comment: The loop executes correctly twice before failing on the third iteration, and countryCode has type `String`.

Comment: @aerophage so what? The field of the object can be null without the object being null.

Comment: I also verified immediately before the method was called that the countryCode was not null.

Comment: What about the other fields? Especially ones where you are comparing them using arithmetic operators like == and <